# Scrapy: trigger X requests wait some time and trigger X request more

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm writing a spider which overrides the start_requests function to trigger requests.
My goal is to trigger X requests and wait for them to complete and then trigger X requests more till no request is needed.

How do you suggest me implementing such goal?

My idea was to use a loop inside start_requests that reads X requests from the DB 
and then using yield to trigger the requests till no request available in DB.

is it going to work?

Comment: Why do you need to generate requests in chunks? Isn't [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) setting enough for you?

Comment: I need to parse ~250 pages from a single site.
i dont want to bombard it so i want to do it in chunks.
X requests and then wait like an hour and process the next X requests

Comment: Then use [DOWNLOAD_DELAY](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay) setting